# How to implement batch fetching with Fluent NHibernate when working with Oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, orm, batch-processing

I've tried using Future feature with Oracle but NHibernate does not support it.

I've read some about Batch Fetching feature: http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/performance.html

How could I use it with Fluent NHibernate? how should it be configured?

Comment: I tried to explain you, that `BatchSize(25)` in your mapping *(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986026/)* would do that job. What exactly is not working? I mean your prev question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970680

Comment: It's the first time I've written this question, and the link you sent is not my question so a coincidence if the timing looks near.

Comment: Your question: How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate? (the second link in my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970680). The first link I've sent -- it is the answer. use BatchSize(25) as I've already told you...

Answer (score 4):

To give you the answer how to use batching with fluent:

1) on the colleciton

```
HasMany<MyEntity>(x => x.Entities)
  .BatchSize(100);
```

2) on a class level

```
public MyEntityMap()
{
    Id(x => x....
    ...
    BatchSize(100);
```

This corresponds with the [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch)