# NHibernate SysCache does not cache children objects

Tags: caching, nhibernate, syscache

Hoping for your assistance. 
I have simple master-child sets ("player" and "playerChildObject"). Fetching "players" also fetches their linked children.

**SysCache caches players, however doesn't cache children.**

Here are the objects (both set with Cache.ReadWrite()):

Entities:

```
public class Player
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<PlayerChildObject> PlayerChildObjects { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        PlayerChildObjects = new List<PlayerChildObject>();
    }
}

public class PlayerChildObject
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class PlayerMap : ClassMap<Player>
{
    public PlayerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("id");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("name");
        HasMany(x => x.PlayerChildObjects).KeyColumn("PlayerId")
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
        Table("accounts");
        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}

public class PlayerChildObjectMap : ClassMap<PlayerChildObject>
{
    public PlayerChildObjectMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("id");
        References<Player>(x => x.Player, "playerId");
        Table("playerChildObjects");
        Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

Session factory also with "UseQueryCache" and "UseSecondLevelCache":

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(cs => ...))
.Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().UseSecondLevelCache()
.ProviderClass(typeof (NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider).AssemblyQualifiedName))
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PlayerChildObjectMap>())
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

And the query itself with SetCacheable(true).SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal):

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        players = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Player))
            .SetCacheable(true)
            .SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal)
            .List<Player>();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

However, profiler shows that Players are cached (called only the 1st time executing players fetch code), while the same PlayerChildObjects are retrieved each time by PlayerID.

So, first request gives N+1 DB calls (list of players + child objects by each player), all consecutive requests execute N calls (child objects by each player).

What am I missing? **How to make SysCache caching children as well?**

SysCache version: 3.1.0.4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, there are two issues. Firstly, even the **`one-to-many`**  *(`HasMany`)* does have cache setting:

```
HasMany(x => x.PlayerChildObjects).KeyColumn("PlayerId")
    ...
    .Cache.IncludeAll() // or .IncludeNonLazy, .CustomInclude("customInclude")
        .ReadOnly() // or .NonStrictReadWrite(), .ReadWrite(), .Transactional(),
                    //  .CustomUsage("customUsage")        
        .Region("regionName");
```

Check more abut [HasMany mapping here](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html) (article by Adam Bar about mapping by code, but at the end is fluent one)

The doc [19.2.1. Cache mappings](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#performance-cache-mapping)

Secondly, we should use batch-fetching:

```
public PlayerMap()
{
    BatchSize(25);

    HasMany(x => x.PlayerChildObjects).KeyColumn("PlayerId")
        ...
        .BatchSize(25)
...
public PlayerChildObjectMap()
{
    BatchSize(25);
    ...
```

Read more about it in doc [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#performance-fetching-batch), or here:

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)
- [How to implement batch fetching with Fluent NHibernate when working with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20995583/1679310)

Comment: It does! I skipped batches so far, since expect no more than 10 children for each player. But this line made it:

'HasMany(x =>......).Cache.IncludeAll().ReadWrite();'

Danke!

Comment: Great to see that sir! ;) Enjoy mighty NHiberante ;)