# Fluent nhibernate map multiple tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an UserEntity that mapped like and got 
 ***Cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags.*** error

```
public UserEntityMap : ClassMap<UserEntity>
{
   //Other properties
   HasMany(x => x.Addresses).KeyColumn("User_id").Fetch.Join();
   HasMany(x => x.Roles).KeyColumn("User_id").Fetch.Join();
}
```

I want to get both addresses and roles when i create a query for userentity. 
What should i do to see an output like

```
Select * from UserEntity u 
  join Addresses a on u.id=a.User_id 
  join Roles r on u.id=r.User_id where u.id=?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way how to generate such SELECT statement.

I would suggest to use batch fetching. See these for more details:

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)
- [How to implement batch fetching with Fluent NHibernate when working with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20995583/1679310)

The adjusted mapping:

```
public UserEntityMap : ClassMap<UserEntity>
{
   //Other properties
   HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
       .KeyColumn("User_id").Fetch.Join()
       .BatchSize(100);
   HasMany(x => x.Roles)
       .KeyColumn("User_id").Fetch.Join()
       .BatchSize(100);
}
```

This will allow to query the root entity and with just few SELECTS get also their collections (no 1 + N issue)

Also check [What is the solution for the N+1 issue in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456516/1679310)

Comment: Thanks Radim. Should i avoid to use Join on mapping ? Is it better way to use JoinAlias when querying over UserEntity. Like your GetCats() example, when i will have userlist i will query for childs also wont i?

Comment: My approach is - 1) do join `many-to-one` (star schema), use projections (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24246277/1679310) 2) **NEVER** join `one-to-many`. Use sub-queries to filter over collections (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23772548/1679310) and let NHibernate to load them in batches...