# Fluent Nhibernate loading not falling back on lazy loading? (grandchild entities)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading, eager-loading, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

When querying nhibernate, I'm seeing some odd behavior

When I write a query like this

```
Repository.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Child1).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.child2).Eager
```

It will eagerly grab child1 and child2 entities, but there are grandchildren for child1 and child2 that aren't lazily loaded.  I'm a bit confused on how to achieve this.

In my nhibernate mappings, it seems to have no affect on the laziness or eagerness of grandchildren and I require at least some entities be eagerly loaded to avoid the N+1 query problem.

I'm also wondering how I could eagerly load grandchildren entities under my original entity.

Any help or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: The way to go is [batch fetching](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310) and here it is in [fluent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20999028/1679310)

Comment: At what level(s) in my mapping do I need to declare batching?  Then does anything need to be done in the query API to make sure it uses the batches?  Sorry, Nhibernate can be really unclear about this in documentation

Comment: I put all the information into answer. hope it will help a bit

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [batch-fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310). As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999028/1679310), the fluent syntax is:

1) the *collection* setting

```
HasMany<MyEntity>(x => x.Entities)
  .BatchSize(100);
```

2) the *class* level setting

```
public MyEntityMap()
{
    Id(x => x....
    ...
    BatchSize(100);
```

This setting should be applied on every collection and every class. To do that with fluent - we can use **`Conventions`** - see more e.g. [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Available-conventions#interfaces)

> `'IClassConvention'` - Use to alter your ClassMaps values. You can't change properties, collections, etc with this convention, only alter the settings such as `Lazy` and **`BatchSize`**.